# Angular7 Drag&Drop on wrapped elements not well formed

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

Code sample:

```
<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" class="drop-list mt-1">
  <span cdkDrag class="badge badge-dark" *ngFor="let item of items">item</span>
</div>

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.items, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  console.log(this.items);
}

.drop-list {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

At this case, as long the list items (span elements) stays in one line drag&drop works as expected, but when the container not have more horizontal space and  these list items falls in the next line (wrapped), then trying drag&drop gives unexpected results and irregular visually moves of list items.

I have also test this case using flexbox wrap features, but I am getting the same behavior.

Implementing same case with ng2-dragula gives the right and acceptable result.